# Serial port, database connection and reporting in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I am thinking to migrate from .net to tidesdk as its cross platform. I want to use tideSDK in desktop app development. I have tried wxwidgets but didn't liked it too much. But tideSDK seems to adopt web standards such as html 5 and css3 which is beneficial as i know the technology well. But there are certain considerations to take before moving to new technology. So i have some questions as i dont know tidesdk.

1. Is there serialport library in tidesdk.
2. Can i connect to databases such as Mysql, Mongodb?
3. Is there any reporting and printing engine like crystal report, rdlc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the very first phases of a project with the same requirements, and I'm considering the option of using nodejs to dialog via usb with my custom device, or using the original drivers to establish a socket stream from the serial port to nodejs and then straight in my application.

https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-Examples/tree/master/NodeJS

There is no official way (as far as I know) of using well known reposting solutions, so I guess you'll have to  improvise a little, but, since you are basically building webpages, you might consider using css directives for media="print" and experiment on that a little bit.
Plus if you rely on node, you can give fluentreports a try, looks like a lot of fun :)

https://github.com/Nathanaela/fluentreports

Last but not least, yes, you can have your own local database, and you can maybe use it with node, like (I think) I'm going to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have success using phantomjs and rasterize the html into pdf.
fonts was a bit of an issue at first but I worked around it using svg fonts in my css.

phantomjs is a console binary but you can create a process from TideSDK and then pass in the arguments just like this:

```
p = Ti.Process.createProcess({
args: ['mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2']
});

p.launch();
```